# Can we apply the continuous mapping theorem for the limiting joint distribution of the Tracy-Widom law?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2251), if we denote the $k$ largest eigenvalues by $\lambda_N,\lambda_{n-1},··· ,\lambda_{N-k+1}, $ then for Gaussian ensembles the joint distribution function of rescaled eigenvalues has the limit:

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2)\le s_1,\dots, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2)\le s_k)=F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dots, s_k)
$$

Can we say the gap $\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-k+1}=O_p(N^{-2/3})$ by the continuous mapping theorem?

Comment: What is $n$ here? Also, do you mean $\lambda_{N-k+1}-\lambda_1=O_p(n^{-2/3})$ or $\lambda_{N-k+1}-\lambda_N=O_p(n^{-2/3})$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry, that is a typo. That is $N$.

Comment: What about my second question?

Comment: Then to what result do you want to apply the continuous mapping theorem? The result you cited does not involve $\lambda_1$.

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry. I mean $\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-k+1}$. Because I think that as $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \cdots \lambda_k$. So I want to say if we have $\lambda_k-\lambda_1=O_p(N^{-2/3})$.

Comment: Tracy-Widom only applies to the spacing of first few eigenvalues near the edge of the spectrum; so $\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-k+1}$ is of order $N^{-2/3}$ if $k$ is of order unity, but once $k\gg 1$  that difference is of order $k/N$; in the extreme case $k=N$ the difference $\lambda_N-\lambda_1=4$ --- so definitely not of order $N^{-2/3}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Since (by definition) a limit cannot be variable, the cited convergence result, the way it is written, makes sense only if $k$ is fixed. So, the case $k>>1$ is not under consideration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$The answer is: yes, of course.

Indeed, let $X_{N,i}:=N^{2/3}(\la_i-2)$. By the limit theorem you cited and (say) [Example 2.3, p. 18](https://archive.org/details/convergenceofpro0000bill), the $k$-tuple $(X_{N,N},\dots,X_{N,N-k+1})$ converges in distribution to some $k$-tuple $(Y_1,\dots,Y_k)$ of random variables. So, by continuous mapping theorem, $N^{2/3}(\la_N-\la_{N-k+1})=X_{N,N}-X_{N,N-k+1}$ converges in distribution to $Y_1-Y_k$.

So, $N^{2/3}(\la_N-\la_{N-k+1})=O_P(1)$, that is, $\la_N-\la_{N-k+1}=O_P(N^{-2/3})$, as desired.