# Can we get that $ P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon$?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, random-matrices

Following this question: [Can we apply the continuous mapping theorem for the limiting joint distribution of the Tracy-Widom law?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436028/can-we-apply-the-continuous-mapping-theorem-for-the-limiting-joint-distribution).

We know that

> $$
> \lim_{N\to\infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2)\le s_1,\dotsc, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2)\le s_k)=F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dotsc, s_k).
> $$

Can we say that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon?
$$

Or assume that $(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2),\dotsc, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2))\to (Y_1,\dotsc, Y_{N-k+1})$ in distribution.

The question becomes that
for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
P(Y_N-Y_{N-1}\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon?
$$

---

We can say $N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})=O_p(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability distribution of the spacing $\delta_N=\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1}$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda_N$ and $\lambda_{N-1}$ at the edge of the spectrum decays exponentially for $\delta_N\gg N^{-2/3}$, with a decay rate that is independent of $N$. So no matter how small $\epsilon$, you can always find a $c$ such that $P(N^{2/3}\delta_N\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon$.

I agree with the ChatGPT bot in the deleted answer that $c$ will depend on $\epsilon$, but I do not agree that $c$ will depend on $N$. The scaling with $N$ is fully contained in the mean level spacing $N^{-2/3}$ for large $N$ (Tracy-Widom law).

Comment: So why ChatGPT delete his answer? Is that one not true?

Comment: ChatGPT is a bot, an automated machine that produces answers that sound reasonable but are nonsensical; the answer was deleted by the moderators, like several other similar fake answers; see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5531/chatgpt-strikes-mathoverflow

Comment: So for a fixed number $l$, let $\delta_{Nl}:=\lambda_N-\lambda_l$, we can similar get the same answer? $P(N^{2/3}\delta_{NL}\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon$? Here $c$ will dependent on $\epsilon$ and $l$?

Comment: no, this does not hold; the inequality does hold for  $\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-l}$ with fixed $l$, but not for $\lambda_N-\lambda_l$ with fixed $l$.

Comment: Sure, I mean like for the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \dots \le \lambda_l$, then we have this result for $\lambda_l-\lambda_1$, right? That is for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $c>0$ such that $\lim_{N\to\infty} P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_l-\lambda_1)\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: this holds if you keep $l$ fixed as you send $N\rightarrow\infty$; in that way you ensure that both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_l$ are near the edge of the spectrum; if you let $l$ grow with $N$, say by taking $l$ some fraction of $N$, then it will not hold, because $\lambda_l$ will enter the bulk; and yes, the coefficient $c$ will depend both on $\epsilon$ and on $l$.

Comment: Sure, $l$ is a fixed number.