# Does there exist a constant $c>0$ such that $$ P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})\ge c)\ge 1-\epsilon? $$

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Following this question: [Can we get that $ P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})\le c)\ge 1-\epsilon$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436173/can-we-get-that-pn2-3-lambda-n-lambda-n-1-le-c-ge-1-epsilon).

We know that for $\lambda_N\le \lambda_{N_1}\le \dots le\lambda_1$ (eigenvalues of GOE matrix)

> $$
> \lim_{N\to\infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2)\le s_1,\dotsc, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2)\le s_k)=F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dotsc, s_k).
> $$

Can we say that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1})\ge c)\ge 1-\epsilon?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function of the spacing $\delta_N=\lambda_N-\lambda_{N-1}$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda_N$ and $\lambda_{N-1}$ at the edge of the spectrum decays linearly for $\delta_N\ll N^{-2/3}$, with a slope that is independent of $N$. So no matter how small $\epsilon$, you can always find a $c>0$ such that $P(N^{2/3}\delta_N\le c)\le \epsilon$, or equivalently, such that $P(N^{2/3}\delta_N\ge c)\ge 1-\epsilon$. The coefficient $c$ will depend on $\epsilon$ but it will not depend on $N$.

Comment: Thank you! So this result does not contradict with https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436173/can-we-get-that-pn2-3-lambda-n-lambda-n-1-le-c-ge-1-epsilon?

Comment: no contradiction, the coefficients $c$ are different in the two inequalities, of course, here $c\ll 1$, in your earlier question $c\gg 1$.